# Is it wrong to declare two pointer variables with comma?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{

         string y="hello";

     string* x, *z= &y;

     cout<<x<<endl;
     cout<<*x;
}
```

In the above code, when I delete `*z` I get the correct output (address of hello and "hello"). But, when `*z` is present I get some weird output. Why can't both `z` and `x` store the address of `y`.

Comment: Of `x` and `z`, only `z` is initialized here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shown program is wrong. You provide an initialiser only for `z` and not for `x`. Thus, you've default initialised `x` and it has indeterminate value. When you read the indeterminate value (and indirect through the pointer), the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Why can't both z and x store the address of y.

Two pointers **can** store the same address, but they won't store the same address unless you initialise or assign the pointers to have the same address.

> Is it wrong to declare two pointer variables with comma?

It is possible to declare two pointer variables with a comma, but some people consider declaring more than one entity per declaration as bad style.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to initialize both, have code like this:

```
string *x = &y, *z= &y;
```

Your code only initializes z.

And you talk about deleting z... don't do that. z points to y which was not allocated with new...

Comment: I *think* "delete `*z`" meant removing the declaration of `z`, not `delete *z;`